False rape accusation leads to attempted lynching
I am looking for a movie that I saw some years ago, at a minimum 5 years ago. 
The setting is the American South during Jim Crow and the plot is that a white woman falsely accuses one or several Black men (do not remember which) of rape. This causes the White townspeople to basically start a pogrom against the Black people. 
One scene I remember is where the White mob goes to the neighboring village to rampage there as well, but are stopped by the White inhabitants of that village with guns. 
At the end it becomes known that the rape accusation was false. 
The movie is surely American and I would guess it is from the 80ies or 90ies. 

At first I thought it was A Time To Kill (1996) with Matthew McConaughey and Sandra Bullock, but a few elements are missing from that movie that are in your description.

A Time Kill involved two white racists that raped a black girl.

Rosewood (1997), based on a real event, the Rosewood Massacre in 1923.
Wikipedia summary:

A married white woman, Fanny Taylor, claims to have been beaten and
  raped by a black man. The movie shows a white man, not Fanny’s
  husband, in her bedroom where they have sex. They have an argument and
  strike each other. Some black workers outside heard what was happening
  but did not think they should intervene in white people's business.
  The white residents readily believe Fanny's claim. Hearing of an
  escaped black convict, a posse and other unaffiliated white men from
  Sumner and nearby towns go to Rosewood to investigate. The black
  residents of Rosewood quickly become targeted by a white mob,
  including men from out of state and members of the Ku Klux Klan.
The movie features the fictional character of Mann, played by Ving
  Rhames. Mann is a WWI veteran who is scouting out land to buy. He
  meets and falls in love with Beulah, a woman in Rosewood also known as
  "Scrappie" and has stayed with her in Rosewood. After learning about
  Fanny's accusations, Mann leaves town. As a stranger, he is afraid of
  being lynched as a suspect. Learning of the mob attacks, he returns to
  Rosewood to save Beulah and children she cares for.
Some white men who lived in Rosewood helped black people escape from
  the mob. Railroad conductors smuggled people out of town on the rail
  cars that ran nearby. In the movie, Voight as Wright asks the train
  conductors to pick up the women and children. Other blacks took refuge
  in white people’s homes, including Wright's.
In the movie, the mob believed James Carrier held information about
  the escaped convict Jesse Hunter. Wright let the Sheriff take Carrier,
  because the officer said he only wanted to question him. When Carrier
  said he didn't have any information, he was shot immediately by one of
  the mob. Wright gets upset and the mob accuses him of being soft on
  blacks. The scene shows that many white men did not agree with what
  was going on, but were too afraid to face the mob.
At one point the men of Sumner were following the trail of some black
  men. But when they get to the border of Alachua County, heading toward
  Gainesville, a group of armed white men stopped them. They protected
  their black citizens, saying they were law abiding and peaceful.
Officially the death toll was eight people total, two whites and six
  blacks. Other accounts by survivors and the Afro-American newspapers
  were of a higher toll. The movie portrayed the newspapers as
  contributing to the riot; white men came from neighboring towns and
  even states to put down what was called a "riot."
At the end of the movie, a narrative states that some blacks and one
  white testified as witnesses in court in a 1990s suit by survivors
  against the state for its failure to protect the citizens of Rosewood.
  (In 1982 journalist Gary Moore was the first to break decades-long
  silence about the events at Rosewood.) This was followed by a state
  investigation and report. Florida was the first state to pay
  reparations to survivors and their descendants for racial violence.

I actually thought of the Scottsboro Boys incident first.

Possibly Rosewood (1997) with Ving Rhames, Jon Voight and Don Cheadle. From an IMDb review:

In 1920s Florida, the town of Rosewood is built on an uneasy alliance between black and white citizens. When an influential white woman makes a false accusation that she was assaulted by a black assailant, angry white citizens form a brutal lynch mob determined to either find the culprit, or coerce other black citizens into revealing his whereabouts.

The film was based on a true event. Here's the trailer:




Looks like we both answered at the exact same time.  :D

Timestamp says I somehow won by a nose [49 seconds]. ;) These things happen a lot around here. Let's hope we're right!
